# MYSQL Hibernate Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm getting a new error when launching my spring boot application.

I have an Amazon RDS Mysql Instance and the db is called SMARTPARK

In my application properties I have

```
# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = parkuser
spring.datasource.password = xxxxxxxxxxxx
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/SMARTPARK?useSSL=false

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = false

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

All the permission are correct in the DB (i can access it from shell), but when starting the app I'm getting this error

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'smartpark'
```

I don't know if it is a problem of the db name was case sensitive, but i wrote "smartpark" nowhere in the app...

Comment: I think your naming-strategy might be the problem here. You could add `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` to check your queries and see if it is generating lowercase. Additionally you might try changing your strategy to `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`

Comment: Yes... you are correct the database names are case sensitive.

Comment: Please add a little bit more of the stacktrace

Comment: I had my jdbc url on an application.properties in /config remote dir... trying to put it in application.properties inside the app resource dir,it worked... really strange